# How to build MtG duel decks out of a set of older cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I have some older *Magic: The Gathering* cards:

```
Lands
25  Island
14  Mountain
10  Swamp

U
1   Aura Flux
1   Balloon Peddler
1   Boucing Beebles
1   Buoyancy
1   Cloud of Faeries
1   Delusions of Mediocrity
1   Diplomatic Escort
1   Disappear
1   Fatigue
1   Fledging Osprey
1   Illuminated Wings
1   King Crab
1   Misstep
1   Port Inspector
1   Prodigal Sorcerer
1   Rebuild
1   Saprazzan Raider
1   Slow Motion
1   Weatherseed Faeries
2   Capsize
2   Frantic Search
2   Mental Discipline
2   Scent of Brine
2   Thieving Magpie
3   Counterspell
3   Sigil of Sleep
3   Thornwind Faeries
4   Hermetic Study
4   Horseshoe Crab
4   Rootwater Hunter
4   Vigilant Drake
4   Zuran Spellcaster

R
2   Incinerate
2   Kaervek's Torch
2   Lightning Blast
2   Shock
4   Anaba Shaman
4   Fire Whip
4   Goblin Medics
4   Mark of Fury

B
1   Bone Shredder
1   Cateran Persuader
1   Disease Carriers
1   Ghoul's Feast
1   Insubordination
1   Maggot Therapy
1   Phyrexian Denouncer
1   Plague Beetle
1   Rampart Crawler
1   Scent of Nightshade
1   Sever Soul
1   Slinking Skirge
1   Soul Channeling
1   Specter's Wail
1   Squirming Mass
1   Twisted Experiment
1   Undertaker
1   Unearth
1   Vendetta
2   Skittering Horror

Other
1   Junk River
1   Power Matrix
```

Some *U/R* *little creatures* with black one-ofs something.

I am a *beginner*. Now I'm researching a specific way to **complement** this set of cards so as to build fun and accessible **duel decks**(2) to play with a friend. Is it a good idea to look for common cards in competition [*Legacy*](https://old.starcitygames.com/decks/results/format/3/start_date/20-02-2022/end_date/15-05-2022/w_perc/0/g_perc/0/r_perc/0/b_perc/0/u_perc/0/a_perc/0/order_1/finish/limit/25/start_num/0/) and [*Standard*](https://old.starcitygames.com/decks/results/format/1/start_date/20-02-2022/end_date/15-05-2022/w_perc/0/g_perc/0/r_perc/0/b_perc/0/u_perc/0/a_perc/0/order_1/finish/limit/25/start_num/0/) decks for inspiration for hand picking cards in this duel deckbuilding context?

---

What is a good strategy to **complement** the cards I have to make *duel decks* while maximizing visual and content diversity and maintaining low cost?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell what you're asking. In a couple places you imply that you want to play competitively, but in other places you seem to want to just build a couple decks full of cards with art that you like.

Comment: "I don't think there is a product for 1-2 color(s) out of a specific block?" — Assuming by "out of" you mean "produced as part of" and not "outside of", 1-2 color products are exactly what the intro decks (5 per set) and event decks (currently 1 every other set, previously 1 every set, previously 2 every set) are.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. You're asking about a _lot_ of issues here (count the question marks, for starters). A significant portion seems to be answered by an entire guide on how to build decks, which are many and beyond this format. The rest are, as I said, _lots_ of entirely different, _completely_ separate issues: how to build a duel deck pair, how to find cards with particular kinds of art, terminology, asking for product recommendations, how to deal with expensive cards, etc.

Comment: @illuminÉ Much better, this seems more manageable now

Comment: A good place to ask for card recommendations is [TappedOut.net](http://tappedout.net/). You can build a deck using the cards you have and ask for feedback OR search for existing decks that use the cards you have. Use the "Budget" tag to notify users that you are only wanting to use cheap cards, or to filter results.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you have is actually two 60 card decks already, plus a few extra cards.

Make a Blue deck and a Black/Red deck with 24 lands and 36 spells in each using your existing cards. In the B/R deck make sure to split your colors in the same ratio as your lands are divided. In both decks try to have at least 2/3 of your spells be creatures.
I didn't take a close look at your cards to see if there are any synergies or obviously good/bad cards.

Following the above guidelines should get you to a good starting point for the decks. Play them a 5-10 times and then consider if there were any cards that were either far too good (you always win when you resolve it), too bad (you never wanted to cast it), or unfun (maybe Capsize later in the game). Take those cards out and replace them with ones that are more interesting.

After you've done that for a few play sessions then you might consider actually buying cards, either by increasing the count of the cards you like best to 4 (the limit), or by finding a theme or strategy that you like and moving the deck in that direction by cutting cards that don't fit and adding some that do. Searching the internet for "mtg {cardname} combo" or "mtg {cardname} deck" will often yield results that will give you some specific cards to look at. It appears to me that perhaps you are asking how to do this step, and really the answer is that you have to play the decks to find out what you like or don't like about them- there are thousands of cards that could be added to each deck, and each one will take it in a different direction. The one person who is qualified to determine what you like or don't about your decks is you.

Once you have selected some cards that you'd like to buy, you can find them lots of places online simply by searching for "buy mtg {cardname}". Do compare prices of the cards and shipping- online stores often have wildly different prices. Retalier aggregators like TCGPlayer can be useful in this regard.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Thank you, that B/R vs. U split is what I noticed yesterday so I played both sides to see(I used 20 lands per deck). It was slow to open(3-4 turns) but I haven't tried a lot and it's a slow process because I don't know the cards(or the game for that matter, having had a computer take care of the phases too often) well and those sleeves are slippery loll. I may update my listing with type breakdowns to help contributors get a better idea without having to research all the cards I have.